# Making YAML DRY in Ruby

Tags: yaml

In the following example I try to make my config file as DRY as possible without relying on eval in the target source. The first puts gives what expected, the second not, it should also give "Secret".
Any ideas how to alias a key in a YAML file ?

```
require 'yaml'

CONFIG = YAML.load DATA
puts CONFIG['org2']['ldappassword'] # Secret
puts CONFIG['org3']['ldappassword']  #<<:*DEFAULT['ldappassword'] should be Secret

__END__
org1: &DEFAULT
  treebase: 'DC=Organisation,DC=be'
  ldaphost: 9.9.9.9
  ldapusername: ORG\999999
  ldappassword: Secret
  port: 389

org2:
  <<: *DEFAULT

org3:
  treebase: 'OU=Employees,OU=Accounts,OU=Organiationname,OU=Departments,DC=otherorganisation,DC=be'
  ldaphost: 8.8.8.8
  ldapusername: ORG\999998
  ldappassword: <<:*DEFAULT['ldappassword']
  port: 389
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should "rewrite" default values like this

```
org1: &DEFAULT
  treebase: 'DC=Organisation,DC=be'
  ldaphost: 9.9.9.9
  ldapusername: ORG\999999
  ldappassword: Secret
  port: 389

org2:
  <<: *DEFAULT

org3:
  <<: *DEFAULT
  treebase: 'OU=Employees,OU=Accounts,OU=Organiationname,OU=Departments,DC=otherorganisation,DC=be'
  ldaphost: 8.8.8.8
  ldapusername: ORG\999998
  port: 389
```

Comment: works like thatbut it's a pitty you can't reference subkey values like that

Comment: it is YAML constraint